# In-App Purchase Issue in Purchase Scenario - Kotlin

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase, acknowledgepurchase

I am implementing In-App purchase demo in my android application to learn all the things carefully and deeply.

Now, For that, I have below **three product ids** that I have added in my google play console accounts:

1. consumable_product_coins
2. nonconsumable_product_basic_videos
3. nonconsumable_product_prime_videos

Now, my **xml** contains three buttons each for buying above three products, I am launching purchase flow on click of particular button.

In my **Java file**, I have done as below :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope, PurchasesUpdatedListener {
private lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient

private val prod_coin = "consumable_product_coin"
private val prod_basic_videos = "nonconsumable_product_basic_videos"
private val prod_prime_videos = "nonconsumable_product_prime_videos"
private var recent_purchase = ""

private var job: Job = Job()
private lateinit var mBtnBuyCoins: Button
private lateinit var mBtnBuyBasicVideos: Button
private lateinit var mBtnBuyPremiumVideos: Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    findViews()
    initializePurchaseUpdateListener()
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No SKU Details found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun findViews() {
    mTvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription)
    mBtnBuyCoins = findViewById(R.id.btnBuyCoins)
    mBtnBuyBasicVideos = findViewById(R.id.btnBuyBasic)
    mBtnBuyPremiumVideos = findViewById(R.id.btnBuyPremium)

    mBtnBuyCoins.setOnClickListener {
        recent_purchase=prod_coin
        querySkuDetails(prod_coin)
    }

    mBtnBuyBasicVideos.setOnClickListener {         
        recent_purchase=prod_basic_videos
        querySkuDetails(prod_basic_videos)
    }

    mBtnBuyPremiumVideos.setOnClickListener {
        recent_purchase=prod_prime_videos
        querySkuDetails(prod_prime_videos)
    }
}

private fun initializePurchaseUpdateListener() {
    val purchasesUpdateListener =
        PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
            // To be implemented in a later section.
        }

    initializeBillingClient(purchasesUpdateListener)
}

private fun initializeBillingClient(purchasesUpdateListener: PurchasesUpdatedListener) {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this@MainActivity)
        .setListener(purchasesUpdateListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()

    establishConnectionForBillingClient()
}

private fun establishConnectionForBillingClient() {
    billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.

            }
        }

        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    })
}

fun querySkuDetails(sku: String) {
    val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
    skuList.add(prod_coin)
    skuList.add(prod_basic_videos)
    skuList.add(prod_prime_videos)

    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
    launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build()) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
                // Process the result.
                if (skuDetailsList?.size ?: 0 > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "TOTAL SKUS >> "+skuDetailsList?.size,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()


                    for (i in 0 until (skuDetailsList?.size ?: 0)) {
                        Log.e("INSIDE QUERY ", "" + skuDetailsList!![i])
                        if (skuDetailsList!![i].sku.equals(sku)) {
                            val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList!![i])
                                .build()
                            val responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(
                                this@MainActivity,
                                billingFlowParams
                            ).responseCode
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "No SKU Details found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
}

override fun onPurchasesUpdated(
    billingResult: BillingResult,
    purchases: MutableList<Purchase>?
) {
    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null)       {
        Log.e("On Purcahse Updated >> ", "> " + purchases!!.size)
        mTvDescription.text = "Size : " + purchases.size
        for (purchase in purchases) {
            handlePurchase(purchase)
        }

    } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
        Log.e(">>>Purchase CANCELED", " >> P CAN")
    } else {
        // Handle any other error codes.
        Log.e(">>>ERROR > ", " Other Error Occured")
    }
}

fun handlePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
    if(recent_purchase.equals(prod_coin))
    {
        //for consumable products
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Inside handle purcahse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val consumeParams =
            ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                .build()

        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Purchase Token : >>"+"\n"+purchase.purchaseToken.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, { billingResult, outToken ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // Handle the success of the consume operation.
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Acknowledgement Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Acknowledgement FAILS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })
    }else{
        //for nonconsumable products
        if (purchase.purchaseState === Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                launch{
                    val ackPurchaseResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams.build())
                    }
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"You have already puchased this product",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now, you can see from the code that product1 (coins) is consumable, so I have implemented `consumeAsync` method. For rest, implemented `acknowledgePurchase`.

But, the issue is first time I can buy the coin product normally. From the second time Its showing me that : **"You already own this item"**
Same thing is happening for rest of the two products.

What might be the issue ?

Note : After 5 mins I can buy it again! I am not implementing Subscriptions.

Comment: even it is consumable, you don't need to acknowledge it first ?

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi Will you please explain more, What are you asking ?

Comment: Just checked the documentation. I found the answer of my question

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi Please tryout if you are intrested and let me know if any. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Solutions:

The Issue was there in passing purchaseUpdateListener to billingClient.

Removed Below code :

```
private fun initializePurchaseUpdateListener() {
val purchasesUpdateListener =
    PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
        // To be implemented in a later section.
    }
initializeBillingClient(purchasesUpdateListener)
}

private fun initializeBillingClient(purchasesUpdateListener: PurchasesUpdatedListener) {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this@MainActivity)
        .setListener(purchasesUpdateListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()

    establishConnectionForBillingClient()
}
```

Since I am implementing `PurchasesUpdatedListener` I have to change below lines :

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this@MainActivity)
        .setListener(purchasesUpdateListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()
```

To

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this@MainActivity)
        .setListener(this)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()
```

In short the my `onPurchaseUpdate()` method was not called.